# Add leading zero to make a 4-digit number in Autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I would like to add leading zeros to a number such that it always becomes a 4-digit number. For example, if the number is `12`, then the converted number is `0012`. If it is `122`, the the converted number is `0122`. If it is `1`, the the converted number is `0001`.

How can this be done in Autohotkey?

I am using Autohotkey ver1.1.15

Comment: Have you tried google? These are the [first](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetFormat.htm) [three](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/67892-solvedconditionally-pad-a-numeric-string-with-zeros/) [results](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/21641-padding-a-integer/).

Comment: I did try before asking on StackOverflow. But sometimes, a newbie cannot employ what he reads from googling because it is not easy to understand. This is where a more direct answer which can be found on StackOverflow can be useful.

Comment: I can't follow. Have you clicked on the links? They contain a handful of spoon-feeding answers just like the one you've acctepted right here.

Comment: SetFormat is extremely quirky for AutoHotKey, so I wouldn't just say it is "spoon feeding".  The first link has this in the code sample:  `Var += 0  ; Sets Var to be 000011`.  SetFormat isn't a function, but a variable assignment filter.  To trigger it, you need to "do something" to variables.  In this case, add 0 to it, but logically that code shouldn't be doing anything because you're adding 0, but it does...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Example:

Here's one way to do it:

```
Var := SubStr("0000" Number,-3)
```

Comment: I think you're missing an append:
`Var := SubStr("0000" . Number,-3)`

Comment: Append "." is not need for AHK v1.1+

Answer (score 4):

For anyone still looking for this, it seems like the (debatably) "nicer" way of doing this is to use [`Format`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Format.htm), along with the `0` [flag](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Format.htm#Flags) to specify that you want to add leading zeroes. In general, this would look like:

```
Var := Format("{:0x}", Number)
```

Here, `Format` takes in the contents of the `Number` variable, and adds leading zeroes so that the returned string is x characters long. To get a 4-digit number, you would use `Format("{:04}", Number)`.